# Can I attack a raider I just lied to?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm on a mission against the pencil pushers, and accidently asked the leader for supplies....

I'd rather like to erase their bad work (see what I did there?!) and take the leader out after all, but now I've lied to them I can't see anyway of manually attacking.

Is it possible to manually attack on a mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

The quests in Fallout Shelter are fairly basic and a lot of choices in them are one time deals.

Comment: Sadness, raiders must die!.